# Is there a performance penalty when storing two hash columns in a database table?

Tags: sql, database, performance, hash

We are thinking about introducing a second hash column into our database table. The first hash column stores a hash that is calculated based upon the values of some other fields in the same table. The second hash column should contain hashes that are generated based on values from fields that differ from the dataset used for the first hash column. The hash columns are populated by a routine when data is inserted into the table.

```
^ ID ^      Species    ^   Genus  ^  Family   ^    Order    ^  Class  ^   Phylum   ^ Kingdom  ^                    Hash 1                   ^                      Hash 2                        ^
|  1 | S. tetrahyralis | Syllepte | Crambidae | Lepidoptera | Insecta | Anthropoda | Animalia | hashingfunction(ID, Class, Phylum, Kingdom) | hashingfunction( Species, Genus, Family, Order,  ) |
```

We have two separate routines accessing the table. The first gets values based upon the hash value of the first hash column, the second gets values based upon the second hash column.
Example Code querying the database with a hash value:

```
var hashValue = new byte[hashingFunctionOutputLength];
// fill hashValue
using ( var context = new EntityContext() )
{ 
    var entity = context.Entities.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Hash == hashValue);
}
```

Is there any harm in introducing multiple hash columns except for the computing time used for calculating the two hashes upon inserting the data?
Is it problematic to query the database based on hash values?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you using indexes?

Comment: Using MS SQL Server and indexes. I thought this is a general question, that's why I omitted this info. Sorry.

Comment: what kind of problems are you thinking ,might arise

Comment: I don't see any issues when querying the database with Hash values except when you try to compare to see,if values in two columns are identical,based on their hash..

This problem arises due to SQLServer limiting hash input to 8000 characters,this has been lifted in SQLServer 2016 sp1.Also this applies only when you are using Inbuilt sql hash functions

further i see a lot of advantages,if your hash function is good and won't introduce duplicates

Comment: I was worried that querying the table for hashes might be sigificantly slower than querying the id. The hashes are generated by the program and are stored as fixed width byte arrays in the database. We are not using the built in sql hash functions.